# Performance overhead with R function mclapply

Tags: r, performance, parallel-processing, multicore, mclapply

I am experiencing performance overhead while using R function `mclapply` on quite large datasets. For instance, let's consider the following toy example (it consists in suming the elements of sub-matrices in parallel):

```
n = 30000
X = matrix(rnorm(155*n),155,n)

sum.submatrix.rowwise <- function(i){
    chunks = split(1:155, ceiling(seq_along(1:155)/(155/4)))
    return(sum(X[chunks[[i]],]))
}   
sum.submatrix.colwise <- function(i){
    chunks = split(1:n, ceiling(seq_along(1:n)/(n/4)))
    return(sum(X[,chunks[[i]]]))
}
```

On my quad-core Intel Xeon W3550, the parallel approach is clearly not efficient (speed-up x0.8!) if the sub-matrices are rowwise :

```
system.time( for(i in 1:4) sum.submatrix.rowwise(i) )
# elapsed 0.073 
system.time( mclapply(1:4, FUN=function(i) sum.submatrix.rowwise(i), mc.cores=4) )
# elapsed 0.094
```

but it is much more efficient (speed-up x1.8, still not perfect) if the sub-matrices are colwise :

```
system.time( for(i in 1:4) sum.submatrix.colwise(i) )
# elapsed 0.175 
system.time( mclapply(1:4, FUN=function(i) sum.submatrix.rowwise(i), mc.cores=4) )
# elapsed 0.095
```

In the meantime, I did the same experiment on a 12-core AMD Opteron 6174 and the speed-ups are x1.8 and x3.9 respectively (still with mc.cores=4) !

Since these effects depend on processor architecture, is there any cache problem or memory copying problem that could explain these poor performances? Any suggestions?

Comment: What's your operating system? `sessionInfo`?

Comment: Also, I suggest you use a more robust timing system that uses multiple runs such as `microbenchmark` vs `system.time`

Comment: You're definitely right, I actually always use `microbenchmark`, but for space reason (my question is already long) I choose to show the result of `system.time`. Anyway, `microbenchmark` and `system.time` are concordant on my problem.

Comment: Intel-based machine is on Linux Ubuntu 15.04 with R v3.1.2 / AMD-based machine is on Debian Linux jessie with R v3.1.1.

Comment: I'm on Windows, so can't test `mc.cores>1`. Have you looked at the [Rmpi](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpi/Rmpi.pdf) pacakge?

Comment: Thanxs for your message. I am actually a specialist of openMP and MPI in C++, meanwhile I did not enter into the details of Rmpi. My question is really about the fine understanding of the underlaying mechanisms in mclapply. I know that Windows does not support forks.. Again, thanxs for all ...